# Why an input field is not displaying properly in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have got a website running on localhost, I developed it around 2-3 months ago. Back then, the search box was working as expected in both Firefox and Chrome. But now suddenly it displays incorrectly in Chrome whereas in Firefox it works.

Here is how it looks in Chrome(incorrect):

[image: Search box in Chrome]

And here is how it looks in Firefox(correct):

[image]

This is the problem, Firefox shows the input box correctly but Chrome has messed it up. It worked before but doesn't works now.

Search box on click(Chrome):

[image]

Search box on click(Firefox):

[image]

The only that's messed up is search box, the search icon and close icon displays correctly. Since the last 2-3 months, I didn't change a single character in code. It used to work that time but mysteriously doesn't works now.

Here is the code for the search box and icons:

```
<input id="search" name="q" type="search" required>
<label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
<i class="material-icons">close</i>
```

Also, Chrome is the only browser that is showing it incorrectly, I've tested it in Maxthon Nitro and the results are same as Firefox.

To me it looks like Google has changed something in Chrome with an update. Is there any way I can make it display correctly using styles?

Comment: provide us a link of your website so that we can check

Comment: @GauravAggarwal It's on localhost so can't provide link.

Comment: Make a fiddle then

Comment: we atleast need a demo running or a website link to check

Comment: You should inspect the element to find out where the browser is taking the top/margin/padding/... style from. The "priority" of a style is not the same in all browsers. Without further HTML and CSS we can not assist you.

Comment: In addition to your code, it would be helpful to know the Chrome version.

Comment: why is this tagged jQuery ?

Comment: Dude are you for real?? I mean we asked for a link, you didn't provide one then we asked you for a fiddle still you said not feasible, Do you think the SO community members have some psychic powers to magically figure out your issues or even more fix them? with these 3 lines of code!!! that too sans any CSS.!! >:(

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib I will provide a link soon. I have come across a site called ngrok.com. Using their tools, it is possible to make a localhost website public.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Ok, Good for you, please continue with your helpful attitude. IYKWIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you're using materialize.css. If so, add this to your css and it'll be fine:

```
input[type="search"] {
    height: 64px !important; /* or height of nav */
}
```